# font is small in ubuntu for some program like MobaXterm

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, mobaxterm

on ubuntu, the font is normal and big enough to work correctly but when I open MobaXterm and some other windows the font seems very tiny as you can see in the picture and I can not work probably. what is the reason and what is the solution for the MobaXterm case ?

[image: the problem of the font with MobaXterm]

Answer (score 0):

The problem of MobaXterm is solved as follows:
from settings -> configuration -> display
from the display choose: Graphical interface element size: Huge